# "isConnected()" control Bus command spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to check the status of my TCP Adapter whether it is connected or not.
For this Spring provides a control bus command i.e `@adapter_id.isConnected()` for this purpose reference [spring Documentation --> 32.6 TCP Adapters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html).

The below code flow that provides the Id to the adapter:

```
IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(Tcp.nioClient(hostConnection.getIpAddress(),Integer.parseInt(hostConnection.getPort()))
         .serializer(customSerializer)
         .deserializer(customSerializer)
         .id(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber())).clientMode(true).retryInterval(1000).errorChannel("testChannel").id(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()+"adapter"))
         .enrichHeaders(f->f.header("CustomerCode",hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()))
         .channel(directChannel())
         .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(ConnectionFactory())
         .destination(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()))
         .get();

 theFlow = this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(hostConnection.getConnectionNumber()+"outflow").register();
```

My control bus command method:

```
public boolean isConnectionAdapterConnected(String connectionName) {
        MessageChannel controlChannel = ac.getBean("controlBus.input", MessageChannel.class); 
        String exp = "@"+connectionName+"adapter"+".isConnected()";
    boolean status = controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>(exp));
        return status;
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    org.springframework.expression.EvaluationException: The method 'isConnected' is not supported by this command processor. If using the Control Bus, consider adding @ManagedOperation or @ManagedAttribute.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor$ExpressionCommandMethodResolver.validateMethod(ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor.java:114) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor$ExpressionCommandMethodResolver.resolve(ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor.java:95) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:206) ~[spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:134) ~[spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:54) ~[spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:391) ~[spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:89) ~[spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:116) ~[spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:371) ~[spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:153) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor.java:76) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.ncr.seccom.file.configuration.repository.HostConnectionRepository.isConnectionAdapterConnected(HostConnectionRepository.java:352) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.ncr.seccom.file.configuration.service.HostConnectionService.isConnectionAdapterConnected(HostConnectionService.java:198) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.ncr.seccom.file.configuration.controller.SeccomConnectionController.isConnectionAdapterConnected(SeccomConnectionController.java:100) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

The following control Bus Command are running fine:

- `@adapter_id.start()`
- `@adapter_id.stop()`
- `@adapter_id.retryConnection()`

But `@adapter_id.isConnected` is throwing the above exception.

Please help me with the above issue or is there any other way to find whether my adapter is connected or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the documentation - the method is `isClientModeConnected()`.

Comment: Is it OK, Gary, that the `TcpOutboundGateway` doesn't implement a `ClientModeCapable` ? Because Docs still mention that `isConnected()`

Comment: I don't know what you mean; that documentation only talks about inbound gateways; outbound gateways don't support client mode.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Then it's not so obvious by that doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-gateways

Comment: I'll polish it when I fix the method name.

Comment: Good. Also I wonder why then `TcpSendingMessageHandler` is a `ClientModeCapable` if `TcpOutboundGateway` is not...

Comment: Re-reading the JIRA [INT-1770](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-1770), it appears that I added support for the outbound adapter because somebody explicitly asked for it. I don't remember why I didn't do it for the gateway as well (it was over 7 years ago :) ).

Comment: Yeah... Maybe that's time to remove that from there? Doesn't make much sense to me. We don't do any active connection in other similar client side `MessageHandler`s...

Comment: .... or let's add it do Gateway as well: for symmetry  and consistency with the `TcpSendingMessageHandler` since it really looks like a requirement from that JIRA. However from here it sound like a functionality exactly of the `AbstractClientConnectionFactory` per se...

Comment: @gary artem  thanks for the response ,There is some issue is sending the status of tcp adapter through the calling function, So I have posted another [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816110/return-connection-status-for-tcp-adapter-with-server-connection-factory-client-c) Hope you understand the issue